# JavaScript | ColdFusion - Facebook pixel

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to trigger my Facebook pixel.

This is the problem:

I have my own image pixel installed in a client website, when my pixel is triggered in the client website it sends a request to my server which after some inserts in a db I redirect the request to CFML page (HTML for ColdFusion) which has the pixel code from Facebook like below:

```
  <script>
       // Facebok Pixel Init Code
       fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID');
       fbq('trackCustom', 'myCustomEvent', {});
  </script>
  <noscript>
      <img src="THE_FB_URL/?id=PIXEL_ID&ev=myCustomEvent&noscript=1">
  </noscript>
```

When I directly access the page via a browser it triggers the pixel successfully and I can see it in the Facebook pixel report. But when the request is redirected to the page after the insert to the db the pixel does not trigger.

I think its because the JavaScript and HTML is never added to the DOM so it never gets executed...

Do you know how can I achieve this?

I think if maybe I send an HTTP GET request to the `<img>` tag URL hopefully the Facebook accepts it..

**UPDATE**

So this is what happens, the request I send triggers the event, but @Jules is right. I can't find which ad led to a conversion using this method, the problem is that where pushing traffic to our clients website, in which we can't install any JavaScript code.

I tried to check what cookies Facebook stores so when I make the GET request I send those values too, but this happens:

1 - The ad sends the user to a link like this:

`l.facebook.com/l.php?u=redirect_url&h=some_token_here`

In this page I can check that there is some cookies (I assume these are the values Facebook needs to find which ad led to a conversion)

2 - Then the user is redirected to our clients form page

I tried to check the cookies here too but the cookies don't seem to exist..

I need help people!

Comment: That last sentence appears to be worth attempting.

Answer (score 1):

So guys,

I made it work this way:

Instead of using `CFLOCATION` to redirect the request to the `CFML` page where the Facebook JS snippet is, I directly use `CFHTTP` to request the Facebook Tracking URL. Like so:

```
<cfif #source# eq 'facebook'>
     <cfhttpparam type="url" name="id" value="PIXEL_ID">
     <cfhttpparam type="url" name="ev" value="myCustomEvent">
     <cfhttpparam type="url" name="noscript" value="1">
</cfif>
```

It worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, the below might work. You'll exploit the `noscript` image tag.
I think what you want to return with CFML is a CFLocation to the proper FB pixel URL - rather than cfhttp loading it. This way the client still loads the FB pixel, and you still track it's loading in between.

The browser loads

```
<img src="//your-server.net/trackPixel.cfm?some_vars=some_vals">
```

That CFML does...

```
<!--- DO YOUR STORAGE AND OTHER LOGIC --->
<cfquery>...</cfquery>

<!--- THEN REDIRECT --->
<cflocation url="the_official_fb_image_url.gif" addToken="no">
```

So when the user's browser loads your cfm as an image, reply is to load a different image.

Answer (score 1):

You should not write HTML/Javascript code.

The first conversion pixel is called via an `img` tag so you cannot respond with HTML/Javascript.

All you have to do is return a redirect (301) to your final image pixel. In this case:

```
Redirect 301 THE_FB_URL/?id=PIXEL_ID&ev=myCustomEvent&noscript=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `CFlocation` then no, the scripts will not fire. Instead use a javascript relocation. Give the browser enough time to load the page and fire off the script. Something like so:

```
<script>
    fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID');
    fbq('trackCustom', 'myCustomEvent', {});
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            window.location.href='';
            // or simply: history.go(-1);
        },
        3000
    );
</script>
<noscript>
    <img src="THE_FB_URL/?id=PIXEL_ID&ev=myCustomEvent&noscript=1">
</noscript>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made it work with cfhttp, so i don't need to redirect to the CFML page.

Comment: If you do it with cfhttp, you will lose stats in FB. It's better to let the client browser run off the FB tracking mechanism - so that the client's session and cookies can do their jobs.

Comment: you're right.I cant find wich ad led to a conversion using this method, the problem is that where pushing traffic to our clients website, in wich we cant install any javascript code.